# creating CCTMXLayer dynamically

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I try to create my own tile map dynamically such as some buildings created with the help of database. I try to use CCSprite on object layers. However, when i scroll the map, also CCSprites' move too. I don't want to move all of the Sprites whenever player scrolls the map. (For performance issues)
Then, I decided to create my own CCTMXLayer over the background layer. How can i create my own CCTMXLayer dynamically?

Comment: So you have multiple CCSprites added to a single CCLayer and when you change the position of the CCLayer, the CCSprites move in some weird way? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify an existing tilemap using CCTMXLayer's setTileGID method, so create a tileMap in Tiled (or whatever editor you choose) with a single tile.

Then once you have loaded the map into a CCTMXLayer use the setTileGID to change what the tiles are.

Alternatively you could create a new CCLayer and then just add a sprite for every tile in the game, however, you should probably user a textureAtlas or a batchNode if you decide to take that approach. Then to move the map you just change the position of that layer.